# How can I update a record the same as another record in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// names
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
| 1  | jack  |
| 2  |       |
+----+-------+
```

And here is the expected result:

```
// names
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
| 1  | jack  |
| 2  | jack  |
+----+-------+
```

---

And here is my query:

```
update names set name = ( select name from names where id = 1 ) where id = 2
```

But it throws:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'names' for update in FROM clause

How can I do that?

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your data

Comment: In this case we usually trick MySQL this way `...set name =select name from ( select name from names where id = 1 ) as t ...`

Comment: Isn't it possible to use `self-join`? @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either trick MySQL by nesting the subquery:

```
update names 
set name = select name from ( select name from names where id = 1 ) as t
where id = 2
```

or, you can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
UPDATE names n
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 1) AS t
SET 
    n.name = t.name
WHERE id = 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d68f741/1)

Answer (score 2):

You have to join on the same table with an alias :

```
UPDATE names as t1
INNER join (select name from names where id = 1) t2
SET t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.id = 2
```

Comment: By the way this should be the accepted answer because posted earlier as compared to other one

Comment: Thanks mate, but Giorgos answer is more complete.